Updating Token "validTo" Date
I have created an application in Azure Portal that gives me an access token to the REST api of dev ops: https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1
I am able to successfully use the token to gain access to my PATs and return their information. I would like to run a PowerShell script to update the expiration date of each PAT, in dev ops. I am unable to find the correct permission in Azure Portal to allow me to do that.
The only permissions that pop up for tokens are: vso.tokenadministration and vso.tokens. Neither of these allow me to write the new expiration date to the dev ops Api and believe I need a different permission to do so. I cannot find "vso.token_manage" in available permissions either. Any Suggestions?
Thank you
I am getting an access error that would suggest my permissions are not in the scope of writing back to dev ops. I am using json for the format.

Can you post the code that you are using to obtain the oAuth access token from azure?

Yes. I added to the answer section. Thank you.

Here is a sample PowerShell script for your reference, which runs Azure CLI commands to get the user's AAD token for authentication to update the expiration date of a PAT.
$TenantId = "xxxxxx"
$organization = "xxxxxx"

az login --tenant $TenantId --allow-no-subscriptions
$azureDevopsResourceId = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798"
$token = az account get-access-token --resource $azureDevopsResourceId --query "accessToken" --output tsv

$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + "$token"
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

$updateURL = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$updatebody = @"
{
    "displayName": "testPAT",
    "scope": "app_token",
    "validTo": "2024-09-15T00:00:00Z",
    "authorizationId": "xxxxxx",
    "allOrgs": false
}
"@

$updatedPAT = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $updateURL -Headers $headers -Body $updatebody | ConvertTo-Json
$updatedPAT


Thank you. I gain access to my token in a separate python script then implement. I use the same method to update the PAT as you do in your script.

I thought you would like to run a PowerShell script. While the PowerShell script basically runs Azure CLI commands to get the AAD token for the user who is prompted to sign-in via web browser.
